# std::is_same - Use-case of inherited functions from integral_constant

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

Looking at the implementation of `std::is_same` we can see a few internal functions (inherited from `integral_constant`). Let me copy the g++ code for convenience:

```cpp
  template<typename _Tp, _Tp __v>
  struct integral_constant {
      static constexpr _Tp                value = __v;
      typedef _Tp                         value_type;
      typedef integral_constant<_Tp, __v> type;
      constexpr operator value_type()   const noexcept { return value; }
      constexpr value_type operator()() const noexcept { return value; }
  };

  template<typename, typename>
  struct is_same : public integral_constant<bool, false> { };

  template<typename _Tp>
  struct is_same<_Tp, _Tp> : public integral_constant<bool, true> { };
```

This gives us a couple options on how to use it:

```cpp
  bool a1 = is_same<int, int>{};               // instantiate & then cast implicitly
  bool a2 = is_same<int, int>();               // instantiate & then cast implicitly
  bool a3 = is_same<int, int>::value;          // use static member
  bool a4 = is_same<int, int>{}();             // instantiate & then use operator() 
  bool a5 = is_same<int, int>{}.operator()();  // instantiate & then use operator()
```

I am wondering what use-cases there are for these extra functions, and why would e.g. a short implementation like

```cpp
  template<class, class> constexpr bool is_same = false;
  template<class T> constexpr bool is_same<T,T> = true;
```

not suffice? Then we could just write `bool a = is_same<int,int>` without `{}` or `()` or `::value`.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: `is_same` pre-dates variable templates, by about a decade. In C++11, that was the most straightforward and convenient implementation. It's possible that, if it were being invented now, it'd be designed differently.

Comment: What you describe is spelled `std::is_same_v`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is largely historic. The type traits predated variable templates by a decade, so the option you're proposing is an anachronism. The rest were added piecemeal for usability reasons.

---

`std::integral_constant` was introduced way back in 2003, via [N1424](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1424.htm). So it's very old tech, C++03 tech. At the time, it looked like this:

> ```
> template <class T, T v> 
> struct integral_constant
> {
>    static  const T                value = v;
>    typedef T                      value_type;
>    typedef integral_constant<T,v> type;
> };
> ```

None of the additional member functions you see, and note that `value` was also just `static const`, not `static constexpr`. There was no `constexpr` yet, after all.

Many years later, during development of C++0x, there was a library issue opened ([LWG1019](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1019)) which, given the novel addition of `constexpr`, extended this out to:

> ```
> template <class T, T v>
> struct integral_constant {
>   static constexpr T value = v;
>   typedef T value_type;
>   typedef integral_constant<T,v> type;
>   constexpr operator value_type() { return value; }
> };
> ```

This issue was resolved by [N2976](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2976.html).

The motivation for the conversion function is that it lets you use objects of type `integral_constant` as those values. For certain styles of metaprogramming, if you have a function that returns, say, `true_type` directly, you can use it directy:

```
std::true_type foo();    
if (foo()) { ... }
```

Rather than having to write `if (foo().value)` or something else weird like that. However, for non-boolean constants, the only way to get the value out *given* an object is either to access the `value` member or to do an explicit cast (the latter of which requires you to know the type):

```
constant.value
static_cast<???>(constant)
```

which led to [N3545](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3545.pdf), in 2013, adding in the call operator allowing you to write `constant()` to pull the value back out. Is this last addition really useful? I dunno.

Notably, all of this *predates* variable templates - the first revision of which was [N3615](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3615.pdf). The option you suggest of having `is_same` just being a variable bool template wasn't an option until later. And even with variable templates, it's quite convenient to have different types, so I'm not sure that we would go that route even if it were possible. Hard to say in retrospect.